# can someone hack into my s3 with "AWS-cognito-identity-poolID" that is hard-coded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

First i was hardcoded my aws "accessKey" and "securityKey" in client side JS file, but it was very insecure so i read about "aws-cognito", and implemented new JS in following manner :

[image]

**Still i am confused with one thing that can someone hack into my s3 with "AWS-cognito-identity-poolID" that is hard-coded ? Or any other security steps should i take** ?

Thanks,
Jaikey

Comment: It looks like you are using unauth access which means anyone who has that identity id can upload.

Comment: And how anyone can upload with identity id ?

Comment: If you have set it up to allow unauth access then anyone can use it. That's the point of unauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, s3 bucket is secure if you are using through "AWS-Cognito-Identity-Pool" at client side, also enable CORS which allow action only from specific domain that ensure if someone try direct upload or list bucket, will get "access-denied".

Comment: Yeah that's true, security is just a satisfaction in real, we have made best which we can. I also personally tried putting credential in other aws script but only worked when I uploaded them to allowed domain else it not working

Answer (score 4):

#### Definition of Hack

I am not sure what hacking means in the context of your question.
I assume that you actually mean "that anyone can do something different than uploading a file" which includes deleting or accessing objects inside your bucket.

#### Your solution

As Ninad already mentioned above, you can use your current approach by enabling "Enable access to unauthenticated identities" [1]. You will then need to create two roles of which one is for "unauthenticated users". You could grant that role PutObject permissions to the S3 bucket. This would allow everyone who visits your page to upload objects to the S3 bucket. I think that is what you intend and it is fine from a security point of view since the *IdentityPoolId* is a public value (i.e. not confidential).

#### Another solution

I guess, you do not need to use Amazon Cognito to achieve what you want. It is probably sufficient to add a bucket policy to S3 which grants permission for *PutObject* to everyone.

#### Is this secure?

However, I would **not** recommend to enable *direct* public write access to your S3 bucket.
If someone would abuse your website by spamming your upload form, you will incure S3 charges for put operations and data storage.

It would be a better approach to send the data through Amazon CloudFront and apply a WAF with rate-based rules [2] or implement a custom rate limiting service in front of your S3 upload. This would ensure that you can react appropriately upon malicious activity.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html
[2] https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/lower-threshold-for-aws-waf-rate-based-rules/

Comment: Hi, thanks, as i already disabled direct public read/write access to S3 bucket. 
Also we using WAF. but i want to allow any user to upload his CV, also delete or change to S3, but without his registration on my website. Now i create an IAM role and created access credential that was visible at client side JS, which was insecure because any hacker can use this credential in AWS-CLI, and perform all action: read,write,delete. So we using AWS-cognito, also we enabled CORS on s3 that only specific to my domain, and here my question starts that am i secure now?

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you have set the file r/w credentials of the hard-coded access so that it can only be read by the local node and nobody else. By the way, the answer is always a yes, it is only a matter how much someone is willing to engage themselves to "hack".  Follow what people said here, and you are safe.